# Django REST Framework API request with bad parameters returns all objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When someone requests:

127.0.0.1:8000/api/current_metadata?SOME_FIELD_THAT_DOESNT_EXIST=1

this code returns everything. I want it to return nothing. Some kind of strict setting?

```
class GetCrtMetadata(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = CurrentDeploymentSerializer
    queryset=deployment.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = [field.name for field in deployment._meta.fields]
```

Comment: You have a view which returns everything (`deployment.objects.all()`).  If you pass an unknown querystring parameter it just ignores it, thus returning all.  What you are asking *sounds* reasonable, but is quite unusual and there is no built in way to do it.  What you want is a function like `if no_valid_filters_passed_in_qs(): return []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your invalid params don't make the filter works, so if you want to return empty, you should validate the query params:

```py
class GetCrtMetadata(generics.ListAPIView):
  ...
  
  def is_valid_params(self):
    # Do something to validate the params

  def get_queryset(self):
    """
    Cusotm get queryset
    """

    queryset = super().get_queryset()

    if self.action == 'list' and not self.is_valid_params():
      return queryset.none()
      
    return queryset
```